# Significantly different speeds on raster (netCDF) calculations in R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, r-raster, python-xarray

I have some WRF output data that was subsetted and masked using pythons xarray module.

I'm now performing calculations on raster bricks using R's raster package and finding very different speeds for very similar files.

Knowns:

1. There are 3 netCDF files, all the exact same size - 9.47 GB, that contain 9 variables
2. They all have the exact same dimensions (nrow 327, ncol 348, nlayer 365)
3. All calculations are on individual files (layer calculations)
4. All calculations are on the same variable with the same values (except for the second which is masked)

   ```
   system.time(sum(d97[[1:365]]))
   user  system elapsed 
   5.428   2.771   8.840
   ```

The second file is the exact same file but a masked portion, with all the masked values converted to NaN.

```
system.time(sum(masked_d97[[1:365]]))
user  system elapsed 
10.784   2.157  13.052
```

The last file is a slightly modified version (daily values rather than cummulative values) of the first file.  It was modified using Xarray in Python.

```
 system.time(sum(mod_d97[[1:365]]))
 user  system elapsed 
 22.015   1.773  24.474
```

What on earth is happening here? I'm happy to provide more details (code, ncdumps, etc) as requested.

EDIT: added str() of files

```
d97 <- brick(files[8], varname = "TMIN")
masked_97 <- brick(files[3], varname = "TMIN")
d03 <- brick(files[11], varname = "TMIN")

str(d97)

Formal class 'RasterBrick' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
.. .. ..@ name        : chr "/Users/charlesbecker/Desktop/Data/Project Data/Shiny/WY1997_yearly_stats.nc"
.. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
.. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
.. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num NaN
.. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ nbands      : int 365
.. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
.. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
.. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
.. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 0
.. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 0
.. .. ..@ driver      : chr "netcdf"
.. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
..@ data    :Formal class '.MultipleRasterData' [package "raster"] with 14 slots
.. .. ..@ values    : logi[0 , 0 ] 
.. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
.. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
.. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
.. .. ..@ nlayers   : int 365
.. .. ..@ dropped   : NULL
.. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ attributes: list()
.. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ min       : num [1:365] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf ...
.. .. ..@ max       : num [1:365] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf ...
.. .. ..@ unit      : chr "K"
.. .. ..@ names     : chr [1:365] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
.. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
.. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
..@ title   : chr "TMIN"
..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
.. .. ..@ xmin: num 0.5
.. .. ..@ xmax: num 348
.. .. ..@ ymin: num 0.5
.. .. ..@ ymax: num 328
..@ rotated : logi FALSE
..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
.. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
.. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
    ..@ ncols   : int 348
..@ nrows   : int 327
..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
.. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
..@ history : list()
..@ z       :List of 1
.. ..$ : int [1:365] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

str(masked_d97)

Formal class 'RasterBrick' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
.. .. ..@ name        : chr "/Users/charlesbecker/Desktop/Data/Project Data/Shiny/AVA_WY1997_yearly_stats.nc"
.. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
.. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
.. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num NaN
.. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ nbands      : int 365
.. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
.. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
.. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
.. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 0
.. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 0
.. .. ..@ driver      : chr "netcdf"
.. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
..@ data    :Formal class '.MultipleRasterData' [package "raster"] with 14 slots
.. .. ..@ values    : logi[0 , 0 ] 
.. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
.. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
.. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
.. .. ..@ nlayers   : int 365
.. .. ..@ dropped   : NULL
.. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ attributes: list()
.. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ min       : num [1:365] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf ...
.. .. ..@ max       : num [1:365] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf ...
.. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
.. .. ..@ names     : chr [1:365] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
.. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
.. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
..@ title   : chr "TMIN"
..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
.. .. ..@ xmin: num 0.5
.. .. ..@ xmax: num 348
.. .. ..@ ymin: num 0.5
.. .. ..@ ymax: num 328
..@ rotated : logi FALSE
..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
.. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
.. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
    ..@ ncols   : int 348
..@ nrows   : int 327
..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
.. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
..@ history : list()
..@ z       :List of 1
.. ..$ : int [1:365] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

str(d03)

Formal class 'RasterBrick' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
.. .. ..@ name        : chr "/Users/charlesbecker/Desktop/Data/Project Data/Shiny/WY2003_yearly_stats.nc"
.. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
.. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
.. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num NaN
.. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ nbands      : int 365
.. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
.. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
.. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
.. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 0
.. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 0
.. .. ..@ driver      : chr "netcdf"
.. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
..@ data    :Formal class '.MultipleRasterData' [package "raster"] with 14 slots
.. .. ..@ values    : logi[0 , 0 ] 
.. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
.. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
.. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
.. .. ..@ nlayers   : int 365
.. .. ..@ dropped   : NULL
.. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ attributes: list()
.. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi FALSE
.. .. ..@ min       : num [1:365] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf ...
.. .. ..@ max       : num [1:365] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf ...
.. .. ..@ unit      : chr "K"
.. .. ..@ names     : chr [1:365] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
.. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
.. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
.. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
..@ title   : chr "TMIN"
..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
.. .. ..@ xmin: num 0.5
.. .. ..@ xmax: num 348
.. .. ..@ ymin: num 0.5
.. .. ..@ ymax: num 328
..@ rotated : logi FALSE
..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
.. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
.. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
    ..@ ncols   : int 348
..@ nrows   : int 327
..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
.. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
..@ history : list()
..@ z       :List of 1
.. ..$ : int [1:365] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

system.time(sum(d97[[1:365]]))
user  system elapsed 
5.569   2.219   8.048

system.time(sum(masked_97[[1:365]]))
user  system elapsed 
11.887   2.342  14.569

system.time(sum(d03[[1:365]]))
user  system elapsed 
22.253   1.772  24.879
```

Comment: How do the three files look like on the R side? Could you post the output of str( file ) for each of them in addition to the system.time benchmarks? I'm guessing some difference in the masking for the second file and the modifications in Xarray introduce some notable difference on the R side (maybe some encoding issue?).

Comment: I also think it is stemming from Xarray, however I could not identify any differences (other than missing Unit value in the masked file).

Comment: This does not answer your question, but `system.time(sum(d97))` should be more efficient than `system.time(sum(d97[[1:365]]))`

Comment: Looking at the output of `str` can be deceiving, as these are ncdf files and do not use the "native" drivers. print(object), e.g. `print(d97)` might tell you more about the differences

Answer (score 0):

The most likely difference is that data in your new netCDF file is now compressed differently. Two forms of compression are common with netCDF files:

- scale/offset encoding, e.g., to decode from `int16` via a formula like `scale_factor * values + add_offset`.
- zlib compression on individual chunks of the array (only supported with netCDF4 files).

If you don't slice or manipulate your variables, xarray will preserve compression setting via the `encoding` attribute, but this is generally dropped by xarray operations. See the [xarray docs on reading/writing encoded data](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#reading-encoded-data) for more details.